# Can we kill the "beginner" tag?

Tags: support, tags

The tag [beginner](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) is usually used by beginners to tag their questions, even if they're not actually about being a beginner in any way. If the questions *really* are basics, we have [photography-basics](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography-basics) and [camera-basics](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera-basics), which I think are okay if used sparingly. But I think [beginner](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) really serves no purpose.

There are 75 questions so tagged, so going through by hand is a little tedious. Can a mod nuke it?

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing a little bit of weighing in from the community first. Otherwise, I'm okay with it. :)

Comment: Okay. I added two possibilies to vote up or down.

Comment: Unless we get a flurry of "No" votes, I'll kill it on Monday at some point.

Comment: Apparently I can't kill it... I can only merge it into another. A request for this ability has been hanging around since [at least 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124504/moderators-should-be-able-to-remove-burninate-a-tag-themselves), if not longer.

Comment: I'd merge it into photography basics, but I'm not convinced all should be. That would make the synonym feature kick in though, which would stop further use.

Comment: JoanneC: Want to merge it into [hotography-basics? I can go through those (slowly) and remove it where it's not appropriate

Comment: All done, the tags are merged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This serves no real purpose and should be removed.

Comment: I agree. New users love to point to the existence of tags for allowing off topic questions, and this is a great example of that. i.e. "but you have a video tag so my question about buying a video camera..." Beginner itself really tells us nothing useful about a question because everyone starts at a different place. Theres no reason for an "expert" tag so why have a beginner tag? +1

Answer (score 0):

No, let's leave it. We could potentially have a useful collection of questions about beginners.